# Traverse non-numerical indexes of an array

Tags: php, arrays, traversal

Think I'm missing a basic concept. I want to generate html by traversing through a few different arrays of data. They don't use numbers as indexes so numerical looping doesn't work. I cant figure out how to use a `foreach()` here either. How can I traverse `$price` and `$description` when the indexes aren't numbers?

Sample:

```
$traverser= 0;
while($traverser < $number_of_records)
{
    print $traverser . " - " . $price[$traverser] . "<br />";
    print $description[$traverser];
    $traverser++;
}
```

Partial Sample of the Array Structure:

```
object(phpQueryObject)#2799 (13) { ["documentID"]=>  string(32) "1d62be942498df890cab4ccb78a007a2" ["document"]=>  &object(DOMDocument)#3 (0) { } ["charset"]=>  &string(5) "utf-8" ["documentWrapper"]=>  &object(DOMDocumentWrapper)#2 (17) { ["document"]=>  &object(DOMDocument)#3 (0) { } ["id"]=>  string(32) "1d62be942498df890cab4ccb78a007a2" ["contentType"]=>  string(9) "text/html" ["xpath"]=>  &object(DOMXPath)#4 (0) { } ["uuid"]=>  int(0) ["data"]=>  array(0) { } ["dataNodes"]=>  array(0) { } ["events"]=>  array(0) { } ["eventsNodes"]=>  array(0) { } ["eventsGlobal"]=>  array(0) { } ["frames"]=>  array(0) { } ["root"]=>  &object(DOMElement)#5 (0) { } ["isDocumentFragment"]=>  &bool(true) ["isXML"]=>  bool(false) ["isXHTML"]=>  bool(false) ["isHTML"]=>  bool(true) ["charset"]=>  &string(5) "utf-8" } ["xpath"]=>  &object(DOMXPath)#4 (0) { } ["elements"]=>  array(560) { [0]=>  object(DOMElement)#2239 (0) { } [1]=>  object(DOMElement)#2240 (0) { } [2]=>  object(DOMElement)#2241 (0) { } [3]=>  object(DOMElement)#2242 (0) { } [4]=>  object(DOMElement)#2243 (0) { } [5]=>  object(DOMElement)#2244 (0) { } [6]=>  object(DOMElement)#2245 (0) { } [7]=>  object(DOMElement)#2246 (0) { } [8]=>  object(DOMElement)#2247 (0) { }
```

Comment: Can you show us what your arrays look like ?

Comment: `foreach` seems the logical solution, what do your arrays look like (an example)?

Comment: Added a partial sample of a var_dump on the array. If I do normal functions like count() on the array, it returns the correct number of indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it looks like you need the array keys as well, since you're referencing multiple different arrays, you want the `$a as $k => $v` syntax for `foreach`:

```
foreach($description as $key => $desc)
{
    print $key . " - " . $price[$key] . "<br />";
    print $desc;
}
```

Comment: I got this error when trying that: "Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in /var/www/price.php on line 23". Is this possible when working with an array full of objects without converting first?

Comment: It probably means that you need to convert the values in $price or $description before you try to `print` them.

Answer (score 1):

You can [take your pic](http://www.ideone.com/foy1Q) as to how you want to iterate them:

```
<?php

  $ary = array(   // demo array
    'apple' => 'Apple',
    'orange' => 'Orange',
    'grape' => 'Grape'
  );

  // show the structure
  var_dump($ary); echo "\r\n";

  // use a foreach with the key and value
  foreach ($ary as $key => $val)
    printf("%s => %s\r\n", $key, $val);
  echo "\r\n";

  // just get the raw keys
  $keys = array_keys($ary);
  var_dump($keys); echo "\r\n";
```

output:

```
array(3) {
  ["apple"]=>
  string(5) "Apple"
  ["orange"]=>
  string(6) "Orange"
  ["grape"]=>
  string(5) "Grape"
}

apple => Apple
orange => Orange
grape => Grape

array(3) {
  [0]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  [1]=>
  string(6) "orange"
  [2]=>
  string(5) "grape"
}
```

There's always [`array_map`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) & [`array_walk`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I get the question, but it's really as simple as:

```
<?php
$array = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach ($array as $element) {
    echo "{$element}\n";
}
```

This should output "foo" and "bar".